# Unit Tests with Netbeans - unbuffer.dll no such file or directory

Tags: c++, unit-testing, netbeans, mingw-w64, msys2

I am trying to get Google Test v1.7.0 working with Netbeans v8.2 on Windows 10.  I am using Mingw-w64 as the compiler and have installed the mingw-w64-x86_64-gtest package on MSYS2.  I have set the console type to "External Console" in the project settings and have added `-lgtest` to the to the "Additional Options" line on the "Linker" tab in the "Test Files" folder settings.  I have the bare minimal test application possible like so:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

This seems to compile fine, but when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
0 [main] make 1060 C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: /C/Users/Ryan/AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.2/bin/nativeexecution/Windows-x86_64/unbuffer.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT, it seems that this is not unique to gtest, if I make a test using the Netbeans "Simple Test", which has no external dependencies, I also get the same error about unbuffer.dll

Comment: I've been having this same problem. It looks like it was a bug in msys2 that was fixed at one point, but has come back. The workaround was to change the console type to an external terminal under project settings, but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem using cppunit and found a solution that worked for me here https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/show_bug.cgi?id=269738

What I did is replace the offending unbuffer.dll file with "attachment 164026" file for 64-bit systems on the website. Afterwards the test compiled and ran properly.

Be sure to keep the old version of unbuffer.dll